# Same docker image works in Docker for Windows but not in docker on linux

Tags: linux, windows, oracle, docker

**What I want to achieve**
I want to connect to an oracle database within an oracle container via sqlplus

**What my problem is**
I can connect to the database of the same image within Docker for Windows but not on a linux host

**What I did**

**Windows**

```
c:\>docker pull wnameless/oracle-xe-11g
c:\>docker run -d -p 49160:22 -p 49161:1521 wnameless/oracle-xe-11g
c:\>docker exec -it f79f7aa5222c /bin/bash
root@f79f7aa5222c:/# sqlplus system/oracle
```

Result:

> SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Wed Jul 19 07:28:45 2017
>
> Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
>
> Connected to:
>   Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

**Linux**

```
[xx@yy Docker]$ sudo docker pull wnameless/oracle-xe-11g
[xx@yy Docker]$ sudo docker run --shm-size=2g -d -p 49160:22 -p 49161:1521 wnameless/oracle-xe-11g
[xx@yy Docker]$ sudo docker exec -it cea28583cb1c /bin/bash
root@cea28583cb1c:/# sqlplus system/oracle
```

Result:

> SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Wed Jul 19 07:34:16 2017
>
> Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
>
> ERROR:
>   ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
>   ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist
>   Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
>   Process ID: 0
>   Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0

**Infos**
Linux system:

docker info

> [xx@yy Docker]$ sudo docker info
>   Containers: 1
>    Running: 1
>    Paused: 0
>    Stopped: 0
>   Images: 33
>   Server Version: 1.13.1
>   Storage Driver: devicemapper
>    Pool Name: docker-8:17-4460587-pool
>    Pool Blocksize: 65.54 kB
>    Base Device Size: 10.74 GB
>    Backing Filesystem: xfs
>    Data file: /dev/loop0
>    Metadata file: /dev/loop1
>    Data Space Used: 4.741 GB
>    Data Space Total: 107.4 GB
>    Data Space Available: 23.21 GB
>    Metadata Space Used: 4.289 MB
>    Metadata Space Total: 2.147 GB
>    Metadata Space Available: 2.143 GB
>    Thin Pool Minimum Free Space: 10.74 GB
>    Udev Sync Supported: true
>    Deferred Removal Enabled: false
>    Deferred Deletion Enabled: false
>    Deferred Deleted Device Count: 0
>    Data loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/data
>    WARNING: Usage of loopback devices is strongly discouraged for production use. Use `--storage-opt dm.thinpooldev` to specify a custom block storage device.
>    Metadata loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata
>    Library Version: 1.02.137 (2016-11-30)
>   Logging Driver: journald
>   Cgroup Driver: systemd
>   Plugins:
>    Volume: local
>    Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
>    Authorization: rhel-push-plugin
>   Swarm: inactive
>   Runtimes: oci runc
>   Default Runtime: oci
>   Init Binary: /usr/libexec/docker/docker-init-current
>   containerd version:  (expected: aa8187dbd3b7ad67d8e5e3a15115d3eef43a7ed1)
>   runc version: N/A (expected: 9df8b306d01f59d3a8029be411de015b7304dd8f)
>   init version: N/A (expected: 949e6facb77383876aeff8a6944dde66b3089574)
>   Security Options:
>    seccomp
>     WARNING: You're not using the default seccomp profile
>     Profile: /etc/docker/seccomp.json
>    selinux
>   Kernel Version: 4.11.9-300.fc26.x86_64
>   Operating System: Fedora 26 (Workstation Edition)
>   OSType: linux
>   Architecture: x86_64
>   Number of Docker Hooks: 3
>   CPUs: 8
>   Total Memory: 7.776 GiB
>   Name: yy.domain.de
>   ID: 4YVE:4FQ7:27SF:5JZJ:H6RA:P4H5:TK6O:FAGY:CKHS:RQGQ:3BDS:L7W7
>   Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
>   Debug Mode (client): false
>   Debug Mode (server): false
>   Registry: https://registry.fedoraproject.org/v1/
>   Experimental: false
>   Insecure Registries:
>    127.0.0.0/8
>   Live Restore Enabled: false
>   Registries: registry.fedoraproject.org (secure), registry.access.redhat.com (secure), docker.io (secure)

Docker logs

> [xx@yy Docker]$ sudo docker logs cea28583cb1c
>   Starting Oracle Net Listener.
>   Starting Oracle Database 11g Express Edition instance.
>   /usr/sbin/startup.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*

df

> root@cea28583cb1c:/# df -h
>   Filesystem                                                                                        Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
>   /dev/mapper/docker-8:17-4460587-f479be876efbf45834ea013ac119d63629944a2b315c7cbe7da3a22c1b1e566e   10G  1.9G  8.2G  19% /
>   tmpfs                                                                                             3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
>   tmpfs                                                                                             3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
>   /dev/sdb1                                                                                         110G   89G   17G  85% /etc/hosts
>   shm                                                                                               2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
>   tmpfs                                                                                             3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/firmware

stat

> root@cea28583cb1c:/# stat /
>     File: '/'
>     Size: 253             Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   directory
>   Device: fd01h/64769d    Inode: 131         Links: 22
>   Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
>   Access: 2017-07-11 07:12:36.676904944 +0000
>   Modify: 2017-07-19 07:33:44.026249772 +0000
>   Change: 2017-07-19 07:33:44.216248030 +0000
>    Birth: -

lsnrctrl

> xx@yy:/etc/selinux# lsnrctl status
>
> LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 19-JUL-2017 11:30:37
>
> Copyright (c) 1991, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
>
> Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE)))
>   STATUS of the LISTENER
>   Alias                     LISTENER
>   Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
>   Start Date                19-JUL-2017 07:33:46
>   Uptime                    0 days 3 hr. 56 min. 51 sec
>   Trace Level               off
>   Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
>   SNMP                      OFF
>   Default Service           XE
>   Listener Parameter File   /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/network/admin/listener.ora
>   Listener Log File         /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/cea28583cb1c/listener/alert/log.xml
>   Listening Endpoints Summary...
>     (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE)))
>     (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=cea28583cb1c)(PORT=1521)))
>   Services Summary...
>   Service "PLSExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
>     Instance "PLSExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
>   The command completed successfully

**What I already tried**

I tried both users, oracle and root.
I changed permissions of /u01/app/oracle to 755
I checked selinux, this seems not to be active/installed. At least thats what the docker info tells and I cant find sestatus command and /etc/selinux only contains semanage.conf.
I tried several different oracle images, same result in every container.

**EDIT**
As requested, I tried starting oracle service myself:

```
service oracle-xe start
```

Result of alert_XE.log:

> Starting ORACLE instance (normal)
>   LICENSE_MAX_SESSION = 0
>   LICENSE_SESSIONS_WARNING = 0
>   Picked latch-free SCN scheme 3
>   Using LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST_1 parameter default value as USE_DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST
>   Autotune of undo retention is turned on.
>   IMODE=BR
>   ILAT =19
>   LICENSE_MAX_USERS = 0
>   SYS auditing is disabled
>   Starting up:
>   Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production.
>   Using parameter settings in server-side spfile /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/dbs/spfileXE.ora
>   System parameters with non-default values:
>     sessions                 = 176
>     sga_target               = 576M
>     control_files            = "/u01/app/oracle/oradata/XE/control.dbf"
>     compatible               = "11.2.0.0.0"
>     db_recovery_file_dest    = "/u01/app/oracle/fast_recovery_area"
>     db_recovery_file_dest_size= 10G
>     undo_management          = "AUTO"
>     undo_tablespace          = "UNDOTBS1"
>     remote_login_passwordfile= "EXCLUSIVE"
>     dispatchers              = "(PROTOCOL=TCP) (SERVICE=XEXDB)"
>     shared_servers           = 4
>     job_queue_processes      = 4
>     audit_file_dest          = "/u01/app/oracle/admin/XE/adump"
>     db_name                  = "XE"
>     open_cursors             = 300
>     pga_aggregate_target     = 195840K
>     diagnostic_dest          = "/u01/app/oracle"

Comment: This is off-topic but at this point it isn't clear if it belongs on DBA or SU. You're using a bequeath connection, not TNS, so the listener output isn't relevant - except that it shows no XE service, which just confirms that the DB is down. So something is going wrong after 'Starting ... instance'. You need to look at the Oracle alert log to start with to see why it isn't starting, or is starting and then shutting down. You could also try starting it manually and see what happens.

Comment: Thank you. I edited my post and added the alert log after trying to start the service myself.

Comment: Looks like an issue with --shm-size. What happens when you don't use it?

Comment: OK, so does SQL\*Plus work now or give the same error; and does `lsnrctl services` show the XE service? The SGA and PGA targets look like they'll exceed the RAM you are allocating; why are you using different `run` flags for the two environments?

Comment: shm-size does not do any difference. I just read in several posts that oracle needs bigger shared memory sizes, so I tried this as well (before someone requesting to do so :) ).
lsnrctl services is showing nothing new compared to the lsnrctl status. Its just listing the EXTPROC_FOR_XE entry (service PLSExtProc).

EDIT: To make it a bit more clear: Leaving shm-size out will result in the same problem. And without it its only reserving 64mb shared memory.

Comment: Nothing else is added to the alert log later? What about other diagnostic files (under `/u01/app/oracle/diag`)? And do you see any other differences in the Docker logs, `df`, etc. between the Windows and Linux environments?

Comment: show me env on both containers, pls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the puzzle, finally.

It turned out that SELinux was active. I don't know how I missed that some weeks ago. I definitely checked that, but maybe I was within the container and not the host.
So I ran the container with the --privileged flag and suddenly I can connect to the db.

Thanks for your comments and sorry that I posted it here, you are right @jww. I will make sure to only post programming questions here in the future. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can also edit `/etc/sysconfig/docker` and remove `--selinux-enabled` from options that's usually added by default. Then restart docker service:

```
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

or

```
sudo service docker restart
```